# JS: Open new tab from callback fn (opening in new window, no tab)

Tags: javascript

```
window.open(window.location + 'pdf?' + Ext.urlEncode(params));
```

When I call it from plan code, it opens normal in new tab. When I want to open it from callback ( interaction with server ), It want to open it in new window (not tab). How to fix it?

I have an Api class. When I do

```
Api.getDetail( function (response) { ... })
```

it goes to server and then dealing that callback. I need to call window from this callback.

Comment: Would you create a test case? I don't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: we need to create window before callback function: `var win = window.open`. And then in callback we can change location of this window.

Comment: I'm lost without a code example: don't you pass arguments in window.open? How do you change location after the callback?

Answer (score 0):

This is browser behavior and you can not control it.

*window.open* might open in a new tab on your desktop in your browser, but it's no guarantee that it will do it for other users.

Comment: I said, that in one code and in one browser same commands opens different: window and tab.

Comment: Yes, and that's weird enough. But it would be really bad to think you could control this for any other browser/environment/user.