# window.open doesn't work in geolocation success callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup

I have a link on a page that should open a new tab and show driving directions on Google Maps from the users location via HTML5 Geolocation to point B. I have set up a jsbin of how i've tried to implement this.
Here's the link: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ikotir/2/).

I guess it has to do with that i try to call the window.open in a callback?
If i try the code on the desktop it tries to open a new window, but i want a new tab. I have tried adding '_blank' but it doesn't do the trick...
Also this is supposed to work on a responsive/mobile layout where the user might run iOS and Mobile Safari, and of course you can't open a popup there...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried in FF and both open a new tab

Comment: `window.open` opens a new window. Geolocation is no way related to this.

Comment: @MajidLAISSI chrome opens a new window for me.

Comment: @janbanan I assume you're testing in chrome?

Comment: Most browsers have built-in pop-up blockers.  Make sure your pop-up isn't being blocked.

Comment: @TomPietrosanti it's not blocked..

Comment: Ok, because it worked fine for me, except that the pop-up was blocked.  Which browser are you seeing the problem in?

Comment: Also, opening in a new tab vs a new window is a browser preference on the user's side that you have no control over.  They decide where new windows are opened.

Comment: I have tested this in Chrome and FF (both on PC and Mac). I just can't wrap my head around why the first link doesn't work, while the second link does...

Comment: When i try the first link, Chrome warns me about a popup and blocks it, but the second link opens fine.

Comment: @TomPietrosanti if it depended on the user preference, then why one time `window.open` opens a new tab, and another time it opens a popup ? I'm guessing it's because it's not a direct user interaction but a callback function.. but not sure

Comment: Ahhhh, Ok, now I understand.  I just tried it again, and it opens in a tab when I click the direct link, and as a pop-up from the call-back, even though my preference is to open in a tab.  And I think I have a solution for you :)

Comment: Sounds promising, please share your findings ;)

Comment: Ok, so my findings were inconclusive, but I did find this, which seems to be a near-duplicate of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752980/js-open-new-tab-from-callback-fn-opening-in-new-window-no-tab

Comment: Okay, so i might need to declare a new window outside of the callback, and then set the location of it and open it in the callback? I'll give that a try...

Comment: Or maybe i can set a variable like "locationIsSet" to false, and then set it to true whenever the success callback is done. And add some kind of event listener on that variable, and once it changes to true i can try open the window from a function. Maybe that's a way too complex approach...

Comment: @TomPietrosanti, that link did the trick for me! Thanks!

Comment: Great!  Since that worked, I'll flag this as a duplicate.